# Error in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

hai,
i am trying to add functionality of DotNetNuke CMS with NopCommerce project
my error is

```
Parse error:
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
 <!-- Forms or Windows authentication -->
 <authentication mode="None">
 <forms name=".DOTNETNUKE" protection="All" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
 </authentication>
```

I dont know how to find virtual directory in iis7 and configure our application.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to IIS 7 and find your website.  Right mouse click the folder where your content is and click "Convert to Application".